# $f\in C^2([0,\,1]),\,f(0)=10,\,f(0.5)=1,\,f(1)=7$. Then must $f''$ attain some value?

Tags: analysis

> $f\in C^2([0,\,1]),\,f(0)=10,\,f(0.5)=1,\,f(1)=7$. Then must $f''$ attain some value?

By Cauchy theorem, $\exists\, x_1\in(0,\,0.5),\;f'(x_1)=18;\;\exists\, x_2\in(0.5,\,1),\;f'(x_2)=12$ and $\exists\, x_3\in(0,\,1),\;f'(x_3)=-3$. But I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** We notice
$$
g(x) = f(x) - (30x^2 -33x + 10)
$$ has $0,\frac 1 2 , 1$ as its zeros. Now apply Rolle's theorem (to $g$ and $g'$.)